# Reading in 4 hex values from file and converting to float

Tags: c++, binary

So I have been creating a file format in java but know I need to read in that binary file in from a C++ application.

The binary file just contains a huge number of floating point numbers represented by 4 hex values.

Sample Data in hex:
`FF B6 DD 99 8D FF 39 61 0C 62 FF 42`, `FF B6 DD 99` is a float, `8D FF 39 61` is a float and so on...

How do i read in the file 4 hex values at a time and convert into a float?

```
    std::fstream fRead;
    fRead.open("path");

    if (fRead.fail())
    {
        fRead.close();
    } 
    else 
    {
        char packetPart[3];

        while (true) 
        {
            fRead.read(packetPart, 4);
            //std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << int(packetPart[0]) << std::endl;
            //I was trying to display the hex value but it didn't work.
        }
    }

    fRead.close();
```

Comment: Is the data actually binary data or is it actually the ascii characters of the hex representation? In other words, is that how the file looks precisely or is that the hex representation of the contents of the file?

Comment: To start with you read four bytes into an array of *three* bytes.

Comment: Also, is the data in the file *textual* data,e.g. the *readable string* `"FF B6 DD 99 8D FF 39 61 0C 62 FF 42"`? Or is it a *binary* file? If it's a binary file you need to open the file in binary mode. If it's a text file, you need to handle the spaces between the numbers as well.

Comment: no the data is not textual data but binary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ifstream inp_file("path", ios::binary);
//...
float my_float = 0.0f;
inp_file.read((char *) &my_float, sizeof(my_float));
```

This will only work if your platform has the same floating point implementation as the Java implementation.

By the way, in your code:

```
char packetPart[3];

while (true) 
{
    fRead.read(packetPart, 4);
```

You are reading 4 characters into a 3 character capacity array.  You should ask yourself, "where does the 4 character go?".